# $ax^2+bx+c$ is constructible

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction

If $a$ is constructible, then $\sqrt a$ is constructible. Furthermore, if $a,b,c$ are constructible, then every root of $ax^2+bx+c$ is constructible.

I think I know how to prove the first sentence but I don't know about the second part. Can someone give a proof of this please.

Comment: 1) Write down the roots of $ax^2+bx+c$.  2) Tell us what part of this expression is hard to prove constructible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Quadratic Formula

Roots of the quadratic polynomial $ax^2+bx+c$ are $\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$. The field of constructible numbers are closed under addition, multiplication and roots, so, $a,b,c$ constructible implies the roots are constructible.